# What is the equivalent of array_column in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, array-column

I have a list of dictionary and I want to get only a specific item from each dictionary. My data pattern is:

```
data = [
    {
        "_id": "uuid",
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "id" : 1,
            "price": 100
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "uuid",
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "id" : 2,
            "price": 150
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "uuid",
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "id" : 3,
            "price": 90
        }
    }
]
```

My desired output:

```
formatted_data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "price": 150
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "price": 90
    }
]
```

To formate data I have used iteration (`for`) like

```
formatted_data = []
for item in data:
    formatted_data.append(item['_source'])
```

In PHP I can use [**`array_column()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) instead of `for` loop. So what will be the alternative of `for` in python3 in my case?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
In [11]: [e['_source'] for e in data]
Out[11]: [{'id': 1, 'price': 100}, {'id': 2, 'price': 150}, {'id': 3, 'price': 90}]
```